# A pointer to an array of struct segmentation faults in local scope (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I want to pass a pointer of array into a C function but I keep getting segmentation fault.

So the gist is ...

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct A {
    int cost;
} B
```

In the main file:

```
static B (*arr_p)[] = NULL;
static B arr[30];

void foo(B **item)
{
    printf("cost %d\n",(*item)[0].cost); // seg fault 11 :(
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    arr_p = &arr;
    (*arr_p)[0].cost = -1;
    printf("Cost %d\n", (*arr_p)[0].cost); // works
    foo((B **) arr_p);
}
```

Is there a way to deal with this pesky seg fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to an array to `foo`. You should change the definition of `foo` to accept a pointer to an array.

Change

```
void foo(B **item)
{
   printf("cost %d\n",(*item)[0].cost); // seg fault 11 :(
}
```

to

```
void foo(B (*item)[])
{
   printf("cost %d\n",(*item)[0].cost); // seg fault 11 :(
}
```

The problem was masked because of the cast in `foo((B **) arr_p);` Without the cast you get a warning on that line. It is generally not a good idea to typecast away a warning like this. In this case, it lead to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, you can use the same declaration syntax for both the pointer and the function definitions:

```
struct B {
    int cost;
};

static struct B array[30];

static struct B (*arr_p)[] = NULL;

/* Note the similarity in syntax: */
void f(struct B (*array)[],
/* ..and keep the array size to avoid common mistakes: */
       size_t array_size) {
    printf("%d\n", (*array)[1].cost);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    arr_p = &array;

    f(arr_p, sizeof array / sizeof *array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```